# Jest not able to load underscore

Tags: underscore.js, jestjs

Getting error
TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined

at line 
import _ from 'underscore';

when running Jest-React testcase.

Answer (score 15):

I have run into same error, hope this answer will help. To load an external modules / library into your Jest test suite. first you have to configure the test set up, see the example here.

see more under [setupFiles](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfiles-array)

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  setupFiles : ["./setup-jest.js"]
}
```

---

```
// setup-jest.js
import lodash from 'lodash'
global._ = lodash
```

Instead lodash you can use underscore or any modules / library. 
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 4):

You can just configure the same in the `jest.config.js` itself, **(No need of another file)**

```js
const lodash = require('lodash')

module.exports = {
    ... 
    globals: {
        '_': lodash
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me:

I do not like to have a jest.config.js file, so I use the configuration in package.json:

```
"jest": {
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/setupJest.js"],
  ...
}
```

And in setupJest.js:

```
import _ from "underscore"
global._ = _
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an ugly workaround, but I replaced underscore with lodash in jest config and it worked fine:

```
module.exports = {
…
    moduleNameMapper: {
        underscore$: 'lodash',
    },
…
};
```